# MP4 Converting Problem

Tags: convert, mp4

I have Sony Walkman and i had  convert flv video to mp4 but Sony walkman still cannot read it and give an error 'Cannot play file format cannot supported'..
I also had tired to convert it by ffmpeg and avidemux.
I using Sony walkman NWZ-A726

Comment: Which commands did you use? Which Walkman device do you use?

Comment: There might be a few video codecs for MP4  [the only one I can think of is H.264, but I wouldn't be surprised if there were several], but if you look up what what codecs your walkman supports, then you can use the -vcodec flag in ffmpeg to use a specific codec

Comment: Have you resolved this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [**MikSoft Mobile Media Converter**](http://www.miksoft.net/index.html) for the transcoding task, which features pre-loaded Presets for the Sony Ericsson Xperia and/or Vivaz devices, which should be compatible with your Sony Walkman. Additionally you can use several codecs from within the GUI in order to perform an easy transcodification.

[image]

Screenshot provided for you to see the Profiles Configuration windows.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong codecs, there might be several for MP4.

Take a look at [Arista](http://www.transcoder.org), you can download pre-made conversion presets for Arista from http://www.transcoder.org/presets/, they should be custom-made to include the correct codecs for that device.